# Why is the width of my footer not reaching the full width on smartphone? I'm using Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, mobile, layout, footer

I have a footer styled for my Wordpress site, which is not appearing to reach the full width of the site on mobile. Also, I am always able to scroll width ways, as if the site is wider than the mobile viewport. This only happens on mobile portrait, not on desktop or tablet.

I have all widths set to 100% (the header, the body, the footer and several others) but it seems the footer width renders as 1333px width whereas the header and body widths render as 1349px (as in inspect dev tools on laptop).

I have no fixed widths for any elements set in pixels of over 300px.

The footer is placed outside of the main and the main container but within the body.

I don't think any of the elements within the footer are the problem, as I have removed them and replaced them but the same problem still exists.

Photo included: Gap to right of footer

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please provide your code to well understand the situation.

Comment: Hi there and thanks for the welcome. Which part of the code would you like exactly? The css for the footer, header or body or the html for either or all of these?

Answer (score 0):

This problem maybe because one of your HTML tags on the entire webpage (out of the footer) is bigger then the screen
This problem not from the footer,please check the other parts of the webpage

Comment: Hi @Hazem Nabil, I picked through all the html and, as stated, all widths of major elements are defined as 100% (so should all technically fit to the screen). I have the following in the header, which I doubt is causing the trouble:                                                                                                            
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; minimum-scale=0.25; maximum-scale=1; user-scalable=1;">

Comment: I also cannot see anything relating to width in the functions.php file. Bear in mind that this only happens in mobile portrait view, although there doesn't seem to be anything causing it in my css media queries for that size view either. Would you like me to post the css for the media query? I feel I am about to give up and leave this as is to be honest, it has baffled me for too long and I am only a novice ..

Comment: i see that the "Tweet" is outside the footer.

Comment: when you tell the browser the this DIV's width is 100%, the browser calculate the width of the screen and make itself the same size, but in you situation on the portrait view of the mobile, the content of the div is bigger than the 100%

Comment: to solve this problem, just remove the "Tweet" or make "Upvote" and "Tweet"  in new line

Comment: and Sorry for late in answer

Comment: Hi Nazeem and don't worry about the late answer, I am grateful for your reply. I have actually tried both removing the social links altogether and displaying them stacked on top of one-another, as I had considered the same reason, but that made no difference. I will try this one more time to make sure it is not that and also send you the html to have a look. I hope I can send enough characters for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Hazem and thank you for your reply again. Update: I now know what was causing this problem. A left margin set in pixels on my content div that was set to 80% width was adding to the gap to the right of the footer, but only on mobile view. I then realised that my media queries were not working but I have now sorted that out, hence I have sorted the problem.
Thank you for your help.